# Report Builder: Why isn't my text field sorting alphabetically?

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column in Report builder that is being grouped by `line` then sorted by `line`. The problem is that the column is grouping and sorting based on the number at the end of the field, e.g. the "1" in `LN BM1`. How do I make it so that it looks at the text in front of it too? Would I need to convert this text field into another data type?

Or in a simpler way - I am sorting by going to "Row Groups" in the Grouping pane and right clicking on `line` and going to the sorting tab. [I see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5n1Q.jpg) that I can use an expression. How can I write an expression to convert this text into some other data type that will be correctly sorted?

```
LN BM1
LN BM2
LN KW3
LN BM3
LN BM4
LN KW5
LN BM5
LN BM6
```

Comment: Please show what your data looks like and your query.

Comment: @Siyual Data is shown above and the query is very large and there are a lot of things that my DB Admin will not want me to post. I will edit the question to maybe simplify what I'm looking for.

Comment: You've shown the end result, but without knowing the query you used to get this result, we can't help you.  It sounds you're constructing this value from multiple fields and only sorting by a component of the value.  But that's only an assumption.